# How can I see which IP was used by me on curl?

Tags: curl

I use a VPN and when I access some websites the IP used is different. How can I check what IP was used on curl? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible, i.e. not in a generic way.

The only way is to have the website report the source IP it sees and send it back as a header / part of the payload, etc. (Basically what the websites suggested in the other answer do)

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of such [services available](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/how-find-ip-address-linux). One example:

```
$ curl ifconfig.me
```

If you want to know what IP address curl itself used *locally* you can have -w tell you:

```
$ curl example.com -o /dev/null -w '%{local_ip}\n'
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear. For example, when I access Stack Overflow, they have one IP that was used by me, I want to know what IP they are seeing. As I said, I use a VPN, so there are servers that see different a IP.

Comment: if you access 'ifconfig.me' through the VPN, it tells you what IP address you have on "the outside" of the VPN, as the rest of the world sees you.

Comment: Didn't know about either of these options. Just tried `curl example.com -o /dev/null -w '%{local_ip}\n'` and got an IPV6 address. Is that normal? Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Sure, that just means it used IPv6.

Comment: Accessing 'ifconfig.me' through the VPN doesn't correspond to what I'm trying to achieve. My VPN routes certain websites, I want to access a website and check if it is using my normal IP or the VPN IP.

Comment: Then access one of those websites that tell you which IP it sees you coming from!